# Why the range(2,1) method is not working in python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Can anyone tell me the output of the following program. I tried to
Do it but it isn't working. Here is the code

```
for i in range(2,1):
    print(i)
```

Comment: you are saying go from 2 to 1 while adding 1 each time ... how many 1's must be added to 2 to reach 1? (maybe you want `range(2,1,-1)` )... maybe

Comment: I guess it is working but you are not able to accept the result.

Comment: "It isn't working" is the most useless description for your problem. Tell us what you're expecting and how it's not.